# Can't get correct city name in swift with CLGeocoder

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I tried to get current city name and country name with swift.
Here's my source code.
    // Then in CLLocationManagerDelegate method you can get user's current location coordinates:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    getAddressFromGeocodeCoordinate(manager.location!)

}

func getAddressFromGeocodeCoordinate(locationObj: CLLocation) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(locationObj, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        // Place details
        var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
        placeMark = placemarks?[0]

        // Address dictionary
        print(placeMark.addressDictionary)

        // City
        if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary!["City"] as? NSString {
            print("city:",city)
        }

        // Country
        if let country = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Country"] as? NSString {
            print("country", country)
        }

    })
}
```

But when I want to print city it returns nil.
I also trid `placeMark.subAdministrativeArea` but also it returns nil.

I'm currently located in Dandong city.

My code prints country well. like `country China` but city.

Anybody who knows solution?

Comment: Could you give us some coordinates where it do not works as you expect ?

Comment: @JulienQuere Np, latitude = 40.025411910838, longtitude = 124.343855400189

Answer (score 2):

Check If any error or what's the response of getting `print(placeMark.addressDictionary)`

```
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(newLocation, completionHandler: {(stuff, error)->Void in

        if error {
            println("reverse geodcode fail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if stuff.count > 0 {
            self.placemark = CLPlacemark(placemark: stuff[0] as CLPlacemark)

            self.addressLabel.text = String(format:"%@ %@\n%@ %@ %@\n%@",
                self.placemark.subThoroughfare ? self.placemark.subThoroughfare : "" ,
                self.placemark.thoroughfare ? self.placemark.thoroughfare : "",
                self.placemark.locality ? self.placemark.locality : "",
                self.placemark.postalCode ? self.placemark.postalCode : "",
                self.placemark.administrativeArea ? self.placemark.administrativeArea : "",
                self.placemark.country ? self.placemark.country : "")
        }
        else {
            println("No Placemarks!")
            return
        }

        })
```